# typedef variable inside same class. Is it a good practice?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Initially I was trying to typedef a template class and I got to the "[gotw 79](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm)" article.
And I didn't want to create another class so I ended up doing the following. Basically typedef'ing inside the same class. It works obviously. but is it a good practice?

```
template <typename T,typename L>
class MyClass{
     typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<MyClass<T,L> > shrdPtr;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm not a big fan of it unless you are designing `MyClass` to be specifically used only within shared_ptr objects, at which point I would insist that requirement be enforced.

It's a little ridiculous to put typedefs for every unrelated template instantiation that you might use with a given object.  Just because you might put `MyClass` in a shared_ptr is not a good reason to typedef it there.  You going to put typedefs for std::vector, map, list, unordered_map, set, deque,....etc, etc, etc?

But if `MyClass` extends shared_from_this and has private/protected constructors so that it can ONLY be created and immediately assigned to a shared_ptr then...sure...it's part of the interface.

If you're trying to avoid having to type out long parameter lists to instantiate a shared_ptr for a templated type with lots of parameters then a better bet is an EXTERNAL utility object just like shown in the article you cited:

```
template < typename T >
struct instantiate_shared_ptr { typedef shared_ptr<T> type; };

template < typename after typename > struct my_complex_template {};
typedef my_complex_template<some parameters> mct_1;
typedef instantiate_shared_ptr<mct_1>::type mct_1_sp;
```

Comment: I think that C++0x provides a syntax for "aliasing" template classes. Anybody remembers the syntax?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Template_aliases - I'm loath to recommend them though since they're at least not implemented in the compiler I have to use, which is probably one of the most common.  But yeah, it's another way.  On the other hand, I don't suspect they'd really help with my specific example.

Comment: Thanks Noah. I think Template aliases is the answer for my problem but GCC doesn't support it yet. any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, especially if the name `MyClass_sp` is referred to in client code.

Comment: Erm, where's this `MyClass_sp` supposed to come from?

Comment: @sbi: sry... i changed the post. MyClass_sp is shrdPtr

Comment: That's only appropriate if it would be a valid and reasonable move to change why MyClass_sp is.  That's not a reasonable thing to do in this case.  The shared_ptr object behaves in very specific manners.  If you were to replace that type it had damn well better behave exactly the same or clients are going to break anyway.  To replace shared_ptr you'd have to rewrite it to be more or less exactly the same, so there's really no point in doing so.

Comment: Furthermore, unless `MyClass` is built to take advantage of a specific type of ownership scheme and HAS to be in a shared_ptr (in which case you've enforced it through the interface) it's not `MyClass`s business how clients decide to refer to it.  It's totally the responsibility of the owning client to put it in an RAII object of some type...or not, if you're sadistic.

Comment: @Noah:  You're right.  I wasn't really considering the actual use case OP's code suggests.  I was only replying to the very general question "is a typedef in a class OK?"

Answer (score 0):

This is probably good practice, it makes it simpler if you decide to change the underlying class the `typedef` refers to at a later date and (arguably) saves typos as well as making code easier to read even if it never changes. The particular choice of name here `MyClass_sp` leaves a little to be desired in my opinion though.

Also it's worth thinking carefully if making the typedef public or private is most appropriate, i.e. is it part of your public interface?

Comment: Sure, because you could simply typedef `MyClass_sp` to a `unique_ptr` and everything would behave naturally.

Comment: Agreed, but in the more general case switching between two (compatible) iterators for example would just work naturally.

Answer (score 0):

It's good, IMO.
I used it a lot.
If I want to use a container which element is the type of the my template, I typedef it.
Such as,

```
template <typename T>  
class MyClass {  
private:  
    typedef std::list<T> SomeContainerType;  
    typedef SomeContainerType::iterator IteratorType;
```

Then if I find any other structure more suitable, such as a vector, I can change the type without touching too much code.

Answer (score -1):

A better solution for smart pointer typedefs is to do them after the class definition in the header:

```
namespace N
{
    class A
    {
    };

    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
}
```

This keeps your smart pointer defintion near your class definition while preventing you (and any developers using your code) from having to write code like `A::APtr a(new A)` (which just looks odd).

EDIT:  Since he is concerned with a template class:

```
namespace N
{
    template<class T, class L>
    class A
    {
    };

    template<class T, class L>
    struct A_Instantiator
    {
        typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<A<T, L> > APtr;
    };
}
```

Comment: the problem is you cannot have template typedefs. i.e. I cannot directly create 
    template <typename T,typename L>
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<MyClass<T,L> > shrdPtr;
Thats the reason we use the above approach

Comment: True, however, you can specialize the typedefs if you know what types will be used for T and L.  If you are trying to write completely generic code, then the other solution is required (even if it is ugly to look at).